# How do you get started creating an "app wrapping" solution for iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm curious to know if anyone has information on how to get started with app wrapping in iOS. This is the idea of applying a security/management policy (ie. requiring VPN access) on top of a native iOS app, without requiring a rebuild of the app itself.

I'm interested in the technical details, not so much the functional abilities or "why" app wrapping is a good or bad idea vs integrating with an SDK that can provide the same capabilities.

Comment: When you say technical details, do you mean sample codes to look at or a third party library to view?

Comment: I mean code to look at or instructions on how it is done inside of xcode - anything to get me started.

Comment: Here is a two part tutorial done by ray that is designed for iOS 5 but looking at the code and sample project, you should get the idea of how it is done and I'm sure you can adapt it to iOS 7. Let me know if that is what you're looking for. http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

Comment: This is definitely interesting and useful, but I'm looking to find solutions that don't require any editing of existing source code (which I know exist, just can't find any good documentation!).

Comment: well there are external sdk's that do the job for you. but you have to license them i guess. but everything out there is in the form of a specific tutorial or a bits and pieces. you might have to adapt a bit and write it to your specific need. just saying.:) i will continue looking but without any idea of what you need to secure, it is hard to guide you or provide you with codes.